# Activating VPN fails always after temporary loss of internet connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, connection

I have a few correctly set up VPN connections and use them frequently with `nmcli`. This works most times, but occasionally I can't connect any more with none of my saved VPNs:

```
bytecommander@AlkaliMetal:~$ nmcli -p con up id "MyVPN"
Error: Connection activation failed: unknown reason.
```

I am not sure if it happens only and always after I lost my ethernet connection with activated VPN, but that could be possible.

Did you also experience such behaviour? What trigger s this malfunction? How can I connect to my VPN again without having to reboot the machine?